# Link static library directly into an executable using ld.gold

Tags: linker, static-libraries, elf, gold-linker

I have an `libfoo.a` which contains `_start` and all required symbols for an executable. `ld.bfd -o foo libfoo.a` works smoothly in my case. However, `ld.gold -o foo libfoo.a` fails silently generating an executable with no symbols from `libfoo.a`. Creating an empty `a.o` and link it with `ld.gold -o foo a.o libfoo.a` works.

I was wondering is there any way to directly link a static library into an executable using `ld.gold` without creating a redundant empty object files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the entry symbol explicitly with the `-e _start` option, and the linker will use that to decide that it needs to load the object that defines it.

Unfortunately, gold will not use the implicit start symbol to load an object from the archive library.

Comment: Actually, there's actually a good reason it doesn't work without an explicit entry symbol: the entry symbol is target-dependent, and gold don't know what the target is until we've seen the first object file.